# VSCode insert comment to suppress eslint rule for line

Tags: visual-studio-code

WebStorm and VSCode both detect which eslint rule code has broken

WebStorm also lets you "*Suppress  for current line*".

(Simply automatically insert an eslint ignore comment)

[image: Suppress rule for line]

Is there anything like that for VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can accomplish that using the [VS Code ESLint Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). The feature was introduced with version [1.7.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170) and is controlled with the setting `eslint.codeAction.disableRuleComment`. Its options are listed in the extensions readme.